# Material UI Drawer scrolls background page to top when opening

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/) as the UI package for an app.
In the app I'm using [material-table](https://material-table.com/#/) with a custom infinite scroll.
When a row is clicked, a drawer opens from the right of the webpage.
Once the drawer opens, the background of the drawer (the infinite scroll table and general page) automatically scrolls back to the top of the page.
This makes this page very unfriendly to users.

I've tried the solutions that are mentioned [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/10756), but it doesn't seem to work.
I tried to use it like this:

```
<Drawer ModalProps={{disableRestoreFocus: true}} disableRestoreFocus>{content}</Drawer>
```

I couldn't find anymore information on material-ui github, or here on stack overflow.

Has anyone encountered this issue or know any other options I can try?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For material-ui v4, you can add this attribute on the drawer component:

```
disableScrollLock={true}
```